React.ts print total page and current page on header
`Hi, I need to show the total page and the current page on the header of my pdf generated by printing a page, I can´t predict where it will page-break, because it's a variable content, here's my code:
const PrintComponent = ({children}: any) => {
        return (<>
            <table className="print-component">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>
                    <div>
                    <Header />
                    </div>
                    </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                        {children}
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot className="table-footer">
                    <tr>
                    <td style={{height: '80px'}}>
                    <Footer />
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
            </>
        )
    }

then in the return of the page:
return (
        <PrintComponent>
        <div style={{fontFamily: 'Arial', backgroundColor: 'white', paddingTop: '15px', paddingLeft: '40px', paddingRight: '40px'}}> ...here is my pdf content
        </div
        </PrintComponent>
)

and I need to show the total page and the current page on this code:
const Header = () => {
        return (
            <div className="page-number" style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', gap: '3px', marginBottom: '20px'}}>
                <img style={{width: '150px', marginBottom: '5px'}} src={logo} alt="Logo" />
                <h1 className="aqui" style={{fontSize: '14px', fontWeight: '700'}}>...</h1>
                <h2 style={{fontSize: '13px', fontWeight: '500'}}>{dados.dadosGerais.codigoLoja}-{today?.slice(0,4)}{today?.slice(5,7)}{today?.slice(8,10)}{new Date().toLocaleTimeString().slice(0,2)}{new Date().toLocaleTimeString().slice(3,5)} – Data: {today?.slice(8,10)}/{today?.slice(5,7)}/{today?.slice(0,4)} – Página: {currentPage} de {totalPages}</h2>
                <hr style={{width: '100%', height: '1px', border: '1px solid black'}} />
            </div>
        )
    }

I have tried to calculate the expect height of the document, and some css solutions but nothing works. When I generate the pdf the total pages and current page exists on the bottom of the document: enter image description here`
